# How to handle gRPC a Client Intermittent Connection / Failure / Disconnect?

Tags: c++, networking, grpc

I am running the c++ hello world async examples. [greeter_async_server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) and [greeter_async_client2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2.cc).

I understand that the example doesnt provide error handling but I cannot find anything on this topic. If the client sends a message then disconnects or has intermittent connection then the server will crash it. How do we handle this case?

How would I modify the server/client boilerplate code to check the state of the client? Here is the outputs when you terminate the client too early:

Client Output: (Terminated Console to simulate intermittent connection/disconnect)

```
root@a64893e1b102:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/build# ./greeter_async_client2 
Greeter received: Hello world 9
Greeter received: Hello world 10
Greeter received: Hello world 8
Greeter received: Hello world 7
Greeter received: Hello world 6
Greeter received: Hello world 5
Greeter received: Hello world 4
Greeter received: Hello world 3
Greeter received: Hello world 2
Greeter received: Hello world 1
Greeter received: Hello world 0
Greeter received: Hello world 11
Greeter received: Hello world 12
Greeter received: Hello world 13
^C
root@a64893e1b102:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/build#
```

Server Output: (Upon termination from client, the server will crash..)

```
root@a64893e1b102:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/build# ./greeter_async_server 
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
E1108 23:00:58.703676900   28202 greeter_async_server.cc:156] assertion failed: ok
Aborted
root@a64893e1b102:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/build#
```

**Update:**
In the serverfile I change

```
GPR_ASSERT(ok);
```

to something like this

```
if(ok){
    // do something
}else{
    std::cout<< "RPC Failed" << std::endl;
}
```

This seems to work fine for intermittent connection and disconnects. But Id like to leave this question up for other recommendations to consider.